# I'm trying to transition the opacity of my navbar when scrolling with React spring and Visibility sensor

Tags: reactjs, transition, react-spring

I'm currently trying to implement a Navbar that starts with an opacity of 0 and same with the height to create a nice effect of the Navbar dropping down when scrolling down the page. I am using React-spring and React-visibility-sensor

It work's very well. But there is one small problem, When the page starts up the navbar is present and fade's out first and only then it work's properly. It is like this every time the page renders.

I have tried many different thing's but so far no luck getting it to have an opacity of 0 when the page starts up. Does anyone have a possible solution for this. It would be greatly appreciated.

```
<VisibilitySensor once>
{({ isVisible }) => (
<Spring delay={300} to={{height: isVisible ? 1 : 100, opacity: isVisible ? 0 : 1}}>
{({ height, opacity }) => <header className={headerStyles.header} style={{height, opacity}}>
<div className={headerStyles.overlay}></div>
<div className={headerStyles.heroContent}>
<h1 className={headerStyles.logo}>Logo</h1>
<p className={headerStyles.brand}>
</p>
<p className={headerStyles.description}>
</p>
</div>
<nav className={headerStyles.navContainer}>
<ul className={headerStyles.navList}>
<li>
<Link to="/" activeStyle={{ color: "aqua" }} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeMenuItem}>
Home
</Link>
</li>
<li>
<Link to="/about/" activeStyle={{ color: "aqua" }} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeMenuItem}>
About
</Link>
</li>
<li>
<Link to="/blog/" activeStyle={{ color: "aqua" }} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeMenuItem}>
Blog
</Link>
</li>
<li>
<Link to="/contact/" activeStyle={{ color: "aqua" }} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeMenuItem}>
Contact
</Link>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>}
</Spring>
)}
 
</VisibilitySensor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I added a from value with the Opacity of 0. Now my Navbar work's as it should.